# React Native - storage - No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I initialise my application this way and it work perfectly well as i can use the authentification.

```html
import { initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import { requestTrackingPermissionsAsync } from "expo-tracking-transparency";
import { Settings } from "react-native-fbsdk-next";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "-..",
  projectId: "-",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

However, when i try to use the firebase storage with this function

```html
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage'

export const UploadFile = async(file_uri,name,bucket) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try{

            const parts = file_uri.split(/[\/\\]/)
            const basename = parts[parts.length - 1]

            if(bucket){
                bucket = firebase.app().storage('gs://'+bucket+'.appspot.com').ref(basename)
            }else{
                bucket = storage().ref(basename)
            }

            bucket.putFile(file_uri)
            resolve(bucket)
        }catch(error){
            console.log('Error when uploading the file '+error)
            reject(error)
        }
    });
}
```

I get the error

> No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

for the line `bucket = storage().ref(basename)`

I tried to pass it app as argument as it's a possible argument but it didn't work either.
I tried other solution found on stackoverflow, github, reddit, etc without success either

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the firebase doc is never up to date and the working solution are never the ones on the doc. Anyway, the solution :
Get the storage this way

```html
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app)
```

And Upload function :

```html
import { ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage';
import { storage } from '../firebase';
import { path } from '../classes/path';
import { file } from '../classes/file';

export const UploadFile = async (file_uri, path='', unique='') => {
    try {
        // Get the file name
        const parts = file_uri.split(/[\/\\]/);
        const basename = parts[parts.length - 1];

        const name = file.uniqueName(basename,unique)
        if(path)
            name = path.join(path,name)

        // Get the file content
        const response = await fetch(file_uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const storage_ref = ref(storage, name);

        // Write the file in firebase
        await uploadBytes(storage_ref, blob)

        return storage_ref;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error when uploading the file ', error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```